# Javascript in HTML: How to insert a user input into the middle of a string automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, string, user-input

ProgLang: Javascript in HTML

Issue: I'm getting a user input via a comment box (their name) and want to have it inserted mid strings throughout the rest of the code. For example: 'Are you okay, first name, I was worried!'

I tried to use `${firstname}`, but it didn't print the rest of the string in the resulting comment box.

```
    Enter Your First Name
<br><input type="text" id=firstname name="firstname" onblur="addNameToCommentBox(this)"><br><br>
.
Opening Sentence <br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="addToCommentBox(this);" name="grade" value="statement1. statement1. " + ${firstname}.`+ "statement1. statement1.">Statement1. indentifier user read on page<br> 

    Second Sentence <br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="addToCommentBox(this);" name="grade" value="statement2. statement2.  ">Statement2. indentifier user read on page<br>
    <br>
...
Resulting Block<br>
    <textarea id="comment" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea><br>
</form>
<script>
function addNameToCommentBox(nameElement) {
    var comment = $("#comment");
        comment.val(comment.val() + " " + nameElement.value); }

function addToCommentBox(checkboxElement) {
    var comment = $("#comment");
    if (checkboxElement.checked === true) {
        comment.val(comment.val() + " " + checkboxElement.value);
    } else {
        var currentComment = comment.val();
        currentComment = currentComment.replace(checkboxElement.value, "");
        comment.val(currentComment);
```

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your template like `"statement1.statement1 {0} statement1. statement1."`

And then write a function to get message by passing arguments.

```
function getComment(template, args){
return args.reduce((acc, element) => {
    console.log(element);
    acc = acc.replace(/{\d}/, element);
    return acc;
}, template);}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/gOYJopP

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to use $ before the parameters. Try this

```
<script>
    function addNameToCommentBox(nameElement) {
        var comment = $("#comment");
            comment.val(comment.val() + " " + $(nameElement).value); }

    function addToCommentBox(checkboxElement) {
        var comment = $("#comment");
        if (checkboxElement.checked === true) {
            comment.val(comment.val() + " " + $(checkboxElement).value);
        } else {
            var currentComment = comment.val();
            currentComment = currentComment.replace( $(checkboxElement).value), "");
            comment.val(currentComment);
```